# How to create generic deserializer using Google Protocol Buffer? Using C#

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use Google protocol buffer library for serializing and deserialzing process in C#. I can deserialize using following code`NotificationSet.Parser.ParseJson(json);` And this is working fine.

NotificationSet is auto generated file by .proto.

But here you can see it is not generic. So, instead of specif type i need to make a method in generic way. Can you please advice on this?

Example:

```
public async Task<TResult> Deserialize<TResult, TValue>(TValue value)
    {
        TResult.Parser.ParseJson(value.ToString());
    }
```

Problem is TResult is generic type, so unable to get Parser method from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer.

Try with is code to achieve generic deserialization process using google protocol buffer library.

```
 public async Task<TResult> Deserialize<TResult,TValue>(TValue value)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Type type = typeof(TResult);
            var typ = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == type.Name);
            var descriptor = (MessageDescriptor)typ.GetProperty("Descriptor", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null, null); 
            var response = descriptor.Parser.ParseJson(value.ToString());
            return await Task.FromResult((TResult)response);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```